# secondary server heap size used in weblogic when primary server is in use

Tags: cluster-computing, weblogic-10.x

In our project we are using weblogic application server. We have 2 servers in one cluster and only primary server is in use. But our secondary server is using the maximum heap size which is shown in below image. Can anyone please suggest me what do in this issue.

[image]

Comment: What are the jvm arguments in your startWebLogic or setDomainEnv scripts? Do the logs for your secondary server provide any info?

Comment: No nothing is showing up in logs. I checked with Server Admin but no use he also dont know from where it is coming. As our process is running on first server there will be no logs in second server. But still we are getting some alerts like this.